# Java JFrame Dispose on close not releasing JPanel data

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Im currently working with JFrames and JPanels.

JFrame - Window with buttons etc.
JPanel - Area to be used for paintComponent etc.

I have my ***mainWindow*** and a ***subWindow***

***mainWindow*** is a JFrame that calls ***subWindow*** which is a JFrame with a JPanel on it.

***subWindow*** uses `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` as i do not want to close everything when i close ***subWindow***

***mainWindow*** calls ***subWindow*** via `new subWindow();`

When i close ***subWindow*** and re-open another instance of it, the old paintComponent stuff are still in the JPanel. i.e If i print a circle the first time it will still be there in the new instance of the ***subWindow***.

I've noticed that when ***subWindow*** is re-opened the old variables used are still present instead of well, being new.

How can i manually dump everything when i exit ***subWindow***?
And why is it so when i called a new instance of ***subWindow*** the old variables still remain?

Comment: Multiple JFrames, bad.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/300257

Comment: Do you assign the instance of subWindow to null before reopening it?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for the heads up

Well using multiple JFrames is bad however, it still doesnt answer the question of why the old variables in subWindow still remain although i call new subWindow() each time

Comment: @hd1 Yes but that should be irrelevant since i am calling newSubwindow() no?